# VLC/CVLC bash script

Tags: bash, vlc

I have a list of URLs, over which i need to run VLC in a bash script. For each URL, i wish to run VLC for a couple of minutes (some of them could be infinite netradio URLs) and know if VLC was able to play it successfully. How do I judge through a bash script whether VLC was able to play the URL ? I tried echoing $? (ie the return code), but it always gave me 0 irrespective of whether the URL was played or not. 
Please help !

Regards,
Venky

Comment: Since the return code isn't helping, does VLC report anything else on stdout or stderr?  If not, extending the source code for VLC may be an option (although possibly not a simple one).

Comment: Why not try with mplayer? it's more command line friendly than VLC.

Comment: Finally found a way to do this using the --run-time option! The command "cvlc --run-time 10 <url> vlc://quit" , will open the url, run it for a duration of 10 seconds and then quit. If it couldn`t play the url, it just hangs and does not exit after 10 seconds. A script could be made which will check if vlc is still running after say 15 seconds. If yes, it couldn`t play the URL. Else, it played the url successfully for 10 seconds and has now exited

Comment: Also know that VLC has a LUA interface.  While I haven't played with VLC's LUA interface, LUA is a pretty nifty language, you may be able to code your whole task with LUA

Answer (score 0):

To determine if the video played or not find a message that reflects that it played and grep for it.  Grep for messages that indicate failure.  You can also use --vvv if you want to get more information.  You will see that there are a few distinct messages that get displayed upon success or failure.

Or I would pull the sources and grep for exit codes

find . -name "*.c" | xargs grep "exit("

Then you can get an idea of the exit codes.

Good luck.